# Weird Syntax Error In C in If-else

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax-error

I was programming an apache module. In the middle of the programming, I was opening a file, but I got an error while compiling.

```
32. static int wqb_handler(request_rec* req){
33. // Open and read our requested file
34. const char* p_file = req->filename;
35. 
36. FILE* req_file;
37. if((req_file = fopen(p_file,"r"))==NULL){
38.    return HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
39. }else{
40.     fclose(req_file);
41. }
42. // Required variables
43. const char* content_type_a = "text/html";
44.
45. // Set Headers
46. ap_set_content_type(req,content_type_a);
47. if(req->header_only){
48.    return OK;
49. }
50. 
51. 
52. return OK;
53. }
```

The problem is in that function, I was checking that was the problem, and I think the problem is the if-else statement, the code is written in C, not in  C++.

These are the errors:

```
C:/wqb/wqb1_apache2.c(43) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' in front of 'const'
C:/wqb/wqb1_apache2.c(46) : error C2065: 'content_type_a' : undeclarated identifier
```

Comment: Are // comments allowed in your C compiler?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I count 3 and 3. Looks fine to me.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel - I count 3 of each.

Comment: @uselpa Yes, they are allowed.

Comment: Stab in the dark: a macro? Run the file through the preprocessor only and look at the function again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this is C, and you're not compiling in C99 mode (i.e. with a C89 compiler), remember that all declarations must be directly following the start of a block.
Mixing declarations and code is a C99 feature imported from C++.

It appears you are compiling with a Micrososft Visual Studio Compiler in C mode. Note that William H. Gates III chose to ignore C99 entirely and refuses to update the C implemenation for the third millennium. :-)

Comment: That was fast, I didn't know that about C, thanks a lot! (I'll accept your answer when stackoverflow let me accept the answer... I need to wait some minutes)

Answer (score -2):

*Share with the solution of your problem. It will help the others to understand it more quickly.*

Improve your knowledge about *operators* and *comments*.

You're writing too many unnecessary `{` and `}` in the operators.
For example, your code:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
   printf("Hello");
}
```

More simple/clear code:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   printf("Hello");
```

...........................................................................

Your code (original) may look so (**It's easier to read and understand**.):

```
static int wqb_handler(request_rec* req)
{
    /* Open and read our requested file */
    const char* p_file = req -> filename;

    FILE* req_file;
    if((req_file = fopen(p_file,"r"))==NULL)
       return HTTP_NOT_FOUND;

    else
       fclose(req_file);

    /* Required variables */
    const char* content_type_a = "text/html";

    /* Set Headers */
    ap_set_content_type(req,content_type_a);

    if(req->header_only)
       return 0;

return OK;
}
```

Comment: This totally fails to address the problem, which is not one of brace style or indent.

Comment: The code is not complete. I can't ignore the '{' because there are more than 1 lines inside else and if. I was only trying to compile for see how is was looking and if it worked good.
I know that feature about the '{', and that's not an answer to my problem.

Comment: Well. But you code is difficult to read, there isn't any suspicion. Am I right?

Anyway, it would be better if you present more information. (more code. and described in the code's comments the problem places)

But the problem is solved and it is really good!

Please, judge me strictly. I'm new to SrackOverflow...

Comment: Don't worry :) I appreciate your help! Many people understand my code and many people can't understand it instantly, that depends of the programming-style of each person. If you have any question because you don't understand the code, ask it in a comment, and just put answers according to the solution of the problem. :)

Comment: @Spamdark, roger that! Affirmative.